Video files on an NFS shared drive are not opening when double clicking on the file in thunar
I have an NFS share with video files which I access using the thunar file manager on my Xubuntu.
When I double click (or press Enter) on a file, nothing happens, but if I launch VLC and open the file, it works.
This issue doesn't happen with a CIFS share.
Any ideas?
I try to start thunar from command line and double click on the video file, but there is no error message
the only thing i see is in syslog file :

systemd[1555]: Started
snap.vlc.vlc-c6b5df26-4ce1-49ab-832c-e462506b5c76.scope.

and nothing after.
UPDATE : I think this is a problem of rights. the NFS mount point is on the users directory, and i try to launch the video file which is in a user's directory
I confirm that i have no problem in an other NFS share

Try launching thunar from a terminal, then go to your NFS share and double click on a file. Do you get any error messages in the terminal?
